# HTA back button not working

Tags: html, vbscript, hta

Back button on the below code is not working.  When I click back, its not coming to previous page.  Can anyone suggest how can I make it work?  Thanks for your suggestions.  I tried a lot to check everything possible.  I didn't get this one working.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="Main" 
APPLICATIONNAME="Main Application"
BORDER="thin"
BORDERSTYLE="normal"
CAPTION="yes"
CONTEXTMENU="no"
ICON=""
SHOWINTASKBAR="no"
SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
SYSMENU="yes"
NAVIGABLE="yes"
MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
MINIMIZEBUTTON="no" />
<script language="VBScript" type="text/vbscript">
function doValidation()
dbalias=frmMyForm.test.Value
IF len(dbalias)=0 then
    document.writeln("Please select the Environment and Try again")
    doValidation=False
    document.writeln("<br><tr><td nowrap align=Center colspan=2><input    type=button value=Back name=ClickBack onclick=history.back()></td></tr>")
End if
End function
Sub cmdSubmit_OnClick
if (doValidation()) Then
    dbalias=frmMyForm.test.Value
    MGSBOX DBALIAS
End if
End Sub
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
    <h1 align="center"><font face="Times Roman"   color="blue">Title</font></h1>
    <form action="temp3.php" name="frmMyForm" id="frmMyForm" method="post">
    <fieldset>
    <label>* Select the Test </label>
        <select name="test" id="test">
            <option value="" selected></option>
            <option value="test1">Test1</option>
            <option value="test2">Test2</option>
            <option value="test3">Test3</option>
        </select>
<br>
    <input type="button" name="cmdSubmit" id="cmdSubmit" value="Submit" style="height:25px; width:60px">
</fieldset>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Please define "is not working". Notice, that you can't use [`document.writeln()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) in a way you're using it now. It opens a new document and wipes out all content of the current document.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this horse's mouth](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/ie/en-us/ca470641-9d9d-49de-b916-d8a087308abe/navigation-of-html-pages-within-hta-files), a .HTA does not support a history. That seems plausible, as a .HTA lacks IExplorer's chrome/gui. The link provides a JScript implementation that could be ported to VBScript, although @Teemu's concerns should be dealt with first.

**Update wrt Teemu's comment:**

Another [mouth](http://osticket.com/forum/discussion/78159/runing-in-internet-explorer-html-application-mode-hta) mentioning problems with history - on IE 10. So maybe it **is** a version thing. Interestingly, this horse switched to IE kiosk mode; perhaps that could be another way of solving the OT's real world problem.

Comment: "horse's mouth"? I'm pretty sure I've seen `history` in the list on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Compatibility). However, it's not there anymore. Something similar was asked just a while ago, I did a test, and a HTA run with IE11 actually supports `history`. So, I guess this is a version dependent issue.